# Object-oriented implementation on Expense Tracking App

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented, .net

I am creating a Expense Tracking Application in C# and right now I am trying to build its building blocks in a console app. I Would like to know your feedback if it is in a Object Oriented Design/Structure.

```
namespace ExpenseTrackerOOP
{
    class ExpenseTracker
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Account expense = new Expenses();
            expense.Initialize();

            Account earnings = new Earnings();
            earnings.Initialize();

        }
    }


    public enum ExpenseType
    {
        Food,
        Transportation,
        Utitlities
    }
    public enum AccountTypes
    {
        Expenses,
        Earnings
    }
    public class AccountType
    {
        public AccountTypes Type;
    }

    public abstract class Account
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        public AccountType Type;

        public abstract void Initialize();
    }

    public class Expenses : Account
    {
        public List<Expenses> Expenses_list { get; set; }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Expenses_list = new List<Expenses>(){
                new Expenses() { Value = 10, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Expenses}) },
                new Expenses() { Value = 20, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Expenses}) },
                new Expenses() { Value = 30, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Expenses}) }
            };
        }
    }


    public class Earnings : Account
    {
        public List<Earnings> Earnings_list { get; set; }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            Earnings_list = new List<Earnings>(){
                new Earnings() { Value = 10, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Earnings}) },
                new Earnings() { Value = 20, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Earnings}) },
                new Earnings() { Value = 30, Type = (new AccountType{Type = AccountTypes.Earnings}) }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about how it works, what each block is supposed to do etc.

Comment: `ExpenseType` isn't being used in this code. Why does an `Expenses` account have a list of `Expenses` accounts? Are you confusing your expense accounts class with actual expenses? You'll need two separate classes to represent those (at least normally).

Answer (score 5):

There are several aspects about your code worth reviewing: OO-principles, code conventions, functional design. Since you specifically requested to review OO-design and your question lacks context to review functional design, I'll focus on the former.

---

#### Inheritance

`Expenses` and `Earnings` both derive from `Account` to provide their specific implementation of `Initialze`. Because of a lack of context, I can't make a call about this design. The implementation of both classes does seem off. I don't think you want each instance of these classes to create and store the same fixed list of presets.

---

#### Polymorphism

This is proper use of polymorphism. The declaring type `Account` is the closest fit to enable the use case `Initialize`. The instance type `Expenses` provides the specific implementation of that method.

> ```
> Account expense = new Expenses();
> expense.Initialize();
> ```

---

#### Composition

You have been a bit too diligent in the composition of some of your classes. `AccountType` is a redundant class, which acts only as a wrapper for `AccountTypes` Type. Get rid of it and use `AccountTypes` directly in `Account`.

> ```
> public class AccountType
> {
>      public AccountTypes Type;
> }
> ```

---

#### Encapsulation

`Account` is an abstract class that does not provide an explicit constructor. A public default constructor is implied. It is impossible for derived classes to reduce the scope of the access modifier, hence it's a breach in encapsulation. Consider providing a protected constructor for abstract classes.

```
public abstract class Account
{
    protected Account() {}
}
```

All your properties and fields are mutable. This might be as desiged, but at least think about whether this is a requirement or just lazy design.

> `public decimal Value { get; set; }`

Answer (score 3):

You should consider the possibility to make paradoxical objects. The below is actually possible and valid according to your classes and their properties but makes no sense:

```
Account account = new Expenses { Value = 100.00m, Type = new AccountType { Type = AccountTypes.Earnings } }
```

In other words: When you have a class hierarchy that defines the data types, there is no  need to and it can lead to paradoxical objects having a property that defines the same as the containing class. So an Expenses account is an expenses account by it own definition as subclass to Account and doesn't need the Type property. So get rid of that completely. If you stand on it, you'll have to make it read only and hard code the Type Property on each of the subclasses:

```
public abstract class Account
{
  public abstract AccountTypes Type { get; }
}

public class Expenses
{
  public override AccountTypes Type => AccountTypes.Expenses;
  etc...
```

Alternatively you can remove the subclasses to Account and have an `AccountTypes` member as defining property, but then it isn't much of a class hierarchy.

---